# How to Efficiently Configure Working Item Counts From Applied Energistics

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-applied-energistics

I'm just getting started on the AE mod in FTB Ultimate Mod Pack.  I'm attempting to specify that I want to send all cobblestone, dirt, and gravel over 2048 blocks in the network, to my recyclers.  Currently my setup is 4 Hoppers on top of a recycler, with an [ME Level Emitter](http://ftbwiki.org/ME_Level_Emitter) [ME Export Bus](http://ftbwiki.org/ME_Export_Bus) for each type of block, for each recycler:

[image: Recyclers Front]
[image: Recyclers Back]

Each Export Bus only exports one type of item, and the Level Emitter turns it off once the level of items in the network drop below 2K.

There are a couple things I don't like about this setup:

- It's Expensive
- I have to configure the Min Level for each item, for each hopper.

Is there a good way to allow for one single Level Emitter per block type, rather than one per block type, per recycler?

I was thinking maybe using a Router instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routers are, in my experience, your best bet here, you can configure one router to pull the scrap out  ([set the router to extract from a side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSZGw.png)), and one router to insert the required items ([insert into top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4DfF.png)).

This way you need one Export/Level emitter per type, up to a maximum of 4 per router (technically you can add more per router, but it's messy).
If you want more than 4 types of items you can add another router set to insert at top without problems.

This setup would also be easier to expand as you would just need to run IC2 power further and add the block next to the existing system. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cigZV.jpg)

Comment: Any specific reason why "extract to south" is better then "extract to north" (or any of the other directions)? This is purely dependent on your setup I think.

Comment: Because extract to south is one left click away :) - True you need only point it to one of the sides, which side doesn't matter on a recycler though. I'll edit the post though.

Comment: I was planning on having some hoppers on top of the router to allow for more than 4 types of items.  When I do this, my extract router takes items from the hoppers.  Do I need a machine filter upgrade to be able to specify that I only want the extract router to extract from Recyclers?

Comment: Yeah, that's the main use of a machine filter, however you can also just use a second router set to insert, they ignore other routers. Inserting is also faster this way.